# How can I create Automatic user profile in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-users

how can i create automatic user profile ? is there any way i can create automatic user profile when a user submitted the registration form In django, Like Stack Overflow. In Stack Overflow when a new user created an account with either Gmail, Facebook Or Github The Stack Overflow will create automatic user profile for He/she so He/She can edit it of His/Her choices. I know how to implement an edit functionality using [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView). I just want to create automatic user profile when the form is submitted. can i create an automatic user profile in django if yes then How ?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatar', blank=True, null=True)
    stories = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

my user registration views

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if password == password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email or user name Already taking')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, 
                last_name=last_name, email=email, password=password)
                user.save();
                return redirect('Home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/).

create signals.py

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Profile

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

#this function wake up after a User object save
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: This does't not work. But it's seems like i need to add **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in the settings.py file please. This answer does not create user profile when i created a new user. it is because I did not add **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in the settings.py file ?

Comment: It should be worked AUTH_USER_MODEL  already set inside Django library. You don't need to overwrite it

Comment: Every time i created a new user using this [Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72457346/18982103) the new does not have a profile

Comment: If this project is on GitHub send here the repo's link. I am going to send a pull request

Answer (score 0):

for the first time I take @enes islam answer but it does not work until i add this into my apps.py file:

apps.py file:

```
def ready(self):
    from . import signals
```

@enes islam answer

You need to use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/)

create signals.py

```
 from django.conf import settings 
 from django.db.models.signals import post_save
 from django.dispatch import receiver
 from . models import Profile

 User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

 #this function wake up after a User object save
 @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```